# San Jose Airport Parking with Kids

Tags: children, sjc

Flying out of San Jose International (SJC) for a few days with two very young kids. What is the most convenient airport parking lot when coming with toddlers? Ideally we could walk to the terminal without need of a shuttle. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SJC airport has details of their parking lots [on their website](https://www.flysanjose.com/parking).  Which of the lots will be the best option depends on [which airline you are flying](https://www.flysanjose.com/airlines), and how much you are willing to pay.

There are two terminals at SJC, and whilst they are connected airside (ie, after security) they are not connected landside.  Presuming you are checking bags you will need to go through check-in/security in the terminal you are departing from.

Parking Lots 2 and 3 are multi-level structures direction opposite Terminals A and B respectively, and getting from the car park to the terminal involves walking across and elevated walkway (Lot 2 to Terminal A) or across a pedestrian crossing (Lot 3 to Terminal B). These will always be the most convenient parking, but they are also the most expensive as a result - especially for Lot 3/Terminal B where the available space is smaller.

Parking Lot 5 is beside Terminal B, and Parking Lot 4 is across the road from lot 5.  Both of these are walking distance to terminal B, however depending on where in those lots you park the walk to Terminal B could be as much as 500+ yards.

Economy Lot 1 is not walking distance to either terminal, however has a regular free shuttle bus which picks up in multiple locations in the lot and then drops off in front of both terminals.

There are also a number of off-site parking locations which are cheaper than those on the airport property, but all will require a shuttle trip.

Answer (score -3):

https://www.flysanjose.com/parking gives you the SJC parking map:

[image]

Comment: thanks! is there a way to reserve the lots that are close to the terminals? the link only allows to reserve the economy lot which seems further away.

Comment: Can you, based on this map or your own experience add a suggetion to which parking lot to user? A map is for many people not enough of an answer.

Comment: @traveler_t sorry I don't know

Comment: @Willeke depends on their departing terminal

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, you could ask for that terminal information and edit your answer when you get it.

Comment: @Willekev true but I find the map rather crystal clear.